# How is the number of levels in a 3D-contour-plot set?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Having an array  witch looks like this plotting it as surface:
[image: Surface]

plotting the same array as 3D-contour it only shows 5 levels. Where is set how many levels it shows, and how can I change it?

[image: Countour]

Comment: `V=np.arange(-0.5,0.5,0.1)`
`cont = ax.contour(X,Y,Z,V,cmap=plt.cm.cool,antialiased=True)`
The V sets the levels :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#contour-plots), the function contour passes the arguments to [axes.contour](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.contour). There it is explained how to set the levels:

> contour(X,Y,Z,N)
>   contour N automatically-chosen levels.
>
> contour(X,Y,Z,V)
>   draw contour lines at the values specified in sequence V

Comment: uh, my fault. Did read the docs, but over read this V. thx anyway :D